# What developer conferences/code camps would one go for mobile development?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-mobile, titanium, rhomobile

I maintain and develop on the Windows Mobile platform.

I know the market is changing rapidly with iPhone and Android gaining market shares.

There are also app development platforms like rhomobile/titanium.

Are there any platform/non platform specific mobile conferences this year?

What would be some of the important/useful conferences to attend in the mobile arena?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.devlink.net/ seems to have a mobility track covering Andriod, IPhone and Windows Phone 7 dev. Has anybody been to a devlink before?

Answer (score 4):

[Google I/O](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/) is supposed to have a lot of Android content this year, and the videos from last year are pretty useful. Unfortunately I think its too late to register.

Comment: Yup, it has been sold out for a month or two. Videos for most of the sessions should show up with in a month or two after the event, and a few (particularly keynotes) get published more quickly. Conversely, it's all of Google, not just Android.

Answer (score 2):

For the iPhone, you'd want to go to Apple's [WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/) conference. It hasn't been officially announced for this year, but many sources point to June 28th as its start date.

Comment: In addition, if you can't make it to WWDC, Apple has gone "on the road" with their iPhone Tech Talks the past two years. These are free mini-WWDCs stuffed into one day. However they are incredibly popular so you need to sign up ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't know anything about this camp, but someone else asked about the Big Nerd Android Bootcamp in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602938/big-nerd-ranchs-android-bootcamp-worth-it). The courses were written and are taught by a very active [member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) of the Android community here on Stack Overflow, so at least you know he knows his stuff!

Comment: Thanks! Though my doctor keeps asking me to get more active. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your city, there may be a local meetup of iPhone and/or Android developers. These are typically free or cost a few dollars to attend, so I think they are a great place to start. Check out meetup.com for more.